# Fluent-Nibernate with wpf: Convention to use uNhAddIns...ObservableListType<T> as default?

Tags: wpf, collections, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-collections

I am trying to use Fluent-Nibernate with wpf that require Observable collections (implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface).

At [uNHAddins: Unofficial addins for NHibernate](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/) i found the

```
    uNhAddIns.WPF.Collections.Types.ObservableListType<T>
```

that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. It  can be configured in Fluent-Nibernate like this

```
    namespace FluentNHibernateTutorial.Mappings
    {
        public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
        {
            public StoreMap()
            {
                Id(x => x.Id);
                Map(x => x.Name);
                HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
                 .CollectionType<uNhAddIns.WPF.Collections.Types
                                      .ObservableListType<Product>>()
                 .Cascade.All()
                 .Table("StoreProduct");
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anybody know how to **implement a Convention** with Fluent-Nibernate that always uses **ObservableListType as default IList implementation** ?

Update: The perfect solution would be something that does the replacement with Fluent-NHibernate-Automapper

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public class ObservableListConvention :
    IHasManyConvention, IHasManyToManyConvention, ICollectionConvention {

    // For one-to-many relations
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance) {

        ApplyObservableListConvention(instance);
    }

    // For many-to-many relations
    public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance) {

        ApplyObservableListConvention(instance);
    }

    // For collections of components or simple types
    public void Apply(ICollectionInstance instance) {

        ApplyObservableListConvention(instance);
    }

    private void ApplyObservableListConvention(ICollectionInstance instance) {

        Type collectionType =
            typeof(uNhAddIns.WPF.Collections.Types.ObservableListType<>)
            .MakeGenericType(instance.ChildType);
        instance.CollectionType(collectionType);
    }
}
```

**In response to the question update:**

This convention should work with the automapper like so:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Store>(cfg)
  .Conventions.Add<ObservableListConvention>();
```

Comment: +1 this works fine for me. I removed my previos comments on this answer because you updated your answer accordingly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good to hear. Glad I could help.