# How to use ObservableCollection with Fluent nHibernate?

Tags: c#, wpf, fluent-nhibernate

```
ObservableCollection<ItemPedido> Items
```

But now in Fluent nHibernate i don´t know how to use it.
Is there an easy way to use ObservableCollection with Fluent nHibernate?
I noticed there is a DLL NHibernate.Collection.Observable;

But i don´t know how to replace my current code that uses IList:

```
    public virtual IList<ItemPedido> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set { _Items = value; OnPropertyChanged(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4)); /*OnPropertyChanged("Items");*/ }
    } private IList<ItemPedido> _Items;
```

how to change the above code to make it work with Observable Collection and Fluent nHibernate?

Comment: Can you make it clear what events you're interested in? Specifically, do you want events when NHibernate is populating the collections from the database as part of lazy loading?

Comment: Yes, I would like that the ListBox get automatically populated when nhibernate populates the Collection. And also when I add a item to the Collection. I am using Lazy Loading. Now I am using ListBoxItems.Items.Refresh();  If I use the ObservableCollection, i will not need to call the Refresh method. It will be automatic.

Comment: Okay, but do you want to have an event raised when NHibernate changes the collection on first load?

Comment: I think yes, because I am planning to use it with WPF. So all changes made to the Collection must be Observable by the ListBox, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Keep on using `ObservableCollection<T>` as implementation of `IList<T>` - no need to change the business code.

All you have to do is configure NHibernate to replace the `IList<T>` internally with an NhibernateObservableCollection when doing the lazy loading.

I used

```
uNhAddIns.WPF.Collections.Types.ObservableListType<T>
```

from [Unofficial NHibernate Addins (unhaddins)](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/) for this.

But probaly any other implementation of NhibernateObservableCollection will do as well.

At [fluent-nibernate-with-wpf-convention-to-use-unhaddins-observablelisttypet-as-Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877338/fluent-nibernate-with-wpf-convention-to-use-unhaddins-observablelisttypet-as) you find the example i used to configure the ObservableCollection with Fluent nHibernate.

Note if you want to use `uNhAddIns.WPF.Collections.Types.ObservableListType<T>`:  There is no binary distribution for this so you have to compile uNhAddIns.WPF.dll yourself from c# sourcecode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code from this article - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfNhibernateToolkit.aspx , or you can add a custom data view and wrap your Items property into another one like it's done here - http://www.shawnduggan.com/?p=46 and http://www.shawnduggan.com/?p=84 .